# Big Brackets inside eqnarray

Tags: math-mode, equations, brackets

Can anyone help me in writing the following long expression with in IEEEeqnarray or eqnarray structure?[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
\Sigma^{*}(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S+})&=&E\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S+}-\bm{\beta})\sqrt{n}(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S+}-\bm{\beta})^{'}\right]\\
&=&E\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}\left\{\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S}-\left(1-(p_{2}-2)D^{-1}_{n}\right)I(D_{2}<p_{2}-2)(\hat{\bm{\beta}}-\tilde{\bm{\beta}})-\bm{\beta}\right\}\right]\\
&& \times \>
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you  please provide some codes forming an MWE for those who like to help?

Comment: As Jesse mentioned, show us what you have made already. Not all of us is used to using `IEEEeqnarray`. The multilines inside the `{...}` can be made using the `aligned` env from `amsmath`.

Comment: I am newbie to latex. I am trying to write this expression in latex. For me, I used to write expressions in either EQNARRAY or IEEEEQNARRAY structure but problem is that, How can I make first two brackets too long so that it will cover all the material inside it. I am searching for possible solution for the last two days but no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should let you start.

Use the `aligned` environment to get the equation split in two lines.

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
\Sigma^{*}(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S+})&=
&E\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S+}-\bm{\beta})\sqrt{n}
(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S+}-\bm{\beta})^{'}\right]\\
&=&E\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{n}\left\{\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S}-\left(1-(p_{2}-2)D^{-1}_{n}\right)I(D_{2}<p_{2}-2)
(\hat{\bm{\beta}}-\tilde{\bm{\beta}})-\bm{\beta}\right\}\\
&\times\sqrt{n}\left\{\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S}-\left(1-(p_{2}-2)D^{-1}_{n}\right)I(D_{2}<p_{2}-2)
(\hat{\bm{\beta}}-\tilde{\bm{\beta}})-\bm{\beta}\right\}'
\end{aligned}\right\}\right]
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### EDIT

Since your request of making two consecutive lines, here it is, but notice that I've simply copied the previous one, not certainly typeset the formula in the image.... Replace that with your equation.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
\Sigma^{*}(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S+})&=
&E\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S+}-\bm{\beta})\sqrt{n}
(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S+}-\bm{\beta})^{'}\right]\\
&=&E\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{n}\left\{\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S}-\left(1-(p_{2}-2)D^{-1}_{n}\right)I(D_{2}<p_{2}-2)
(\hat{\bm{\beta}}-\tilde{\bm{\beta}})-\bm{\beta}\right\}\\
&\times\sqrt{n}\left\{\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S}-\left(1-(p_{2}-2)D^{-1}_{n}\right)I(D_{2}<p_{2}-2)
(\hat{\bm{\beta}}-\tilde{\bm{\beta}})-\bm{\beta}\right\}'
\end{aligned}\right\}\right]\\
&=&E\left[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{n}\left\{\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S}-\left(1-(p_{2}-2)D^{-1}_{n}\right)I(D_{2}<p_{2}-2)
(\hat{\bm{\beta}}-\tilde{\bm{\beta}})-\bm{\beta}\right\}\\
&\times\sqrt{n}\left\{\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{S}-\left(1-(p_{2}-2)D^{-1}_{n}\right)I(D_{2}<p_{2}-2)
(\hat{\bm{\beta}}-\tilde{\bm{\beta}})-\bm{\beta}\right\}'
\end{aligned}\right\}\right]
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am unable to execute two consecutive lines of the above solution. any help? @Karlkoeller

Comment: I get following error message:
{Overfull \hbox (31.30872pt too wide) in alignment at lines 315--326
 [] [] [] [][]
[7]
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.345 &=&E\left
               [\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{
? }

Comment: Sorry, I was missing \\ at the end of above line.

Comment: @KashifAli See the edit. And that is a warning, not an error, telling you that the equation doesn't fit in the line.

Comment: @KashifAli If you want it to fit in the line width, use `{\footnotesize\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}`....`\end{IEEEeqnarray*}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Karlkoeller for your support. I am unable to accept the answer as it says that your reputation level is too low.

Comment: @KashifAli You can't upvote, but you can click the green tick below the upvoting arrows....

Comment: I have Done it.

Comment: @KashifAli very good!